# Can KVO be used to observe a global variable?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, key-value-observing

I have a gloabal variable, `User * currentUser;`, which might be changed from any class. I want to save it to `NSUserDefaults` at any change.

Is it possible to use KVO for a global variable like this, or is there any other way to accomplish a similar effect?

I added my app delegate as an observer for `currentUser`:

```
 [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentUser" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

--

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                     ofObject:(id)object
                       change:(NSDictionary *)change
                      context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"currentUser"])
    { 
        NSDictionary * userDict = [currentUser dictionaryRepresantation];

        [UserDefaults setObject:userDict forKey:@"USER_DATA"];
        [UserDefaults synchronize];
    }
}
```

but this is not called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add observers for global variables, KVO only works with properties of objects. You could wrap your global variable inside a getter/setter pair on your app delegate, but then you could also use a regular property since only changes using the setter will fire KVO notifications.

Also, you should not use global variables anyways, not even if you disguise them as a 'Singleton'.

Comment: Agreed, global variables in OOP are something terrible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'll redesign it.